# Nested lists, how I can do this with lambda expression?

Tags: c#, linq, list, lambda

Can't really understand how the select extension method works with a list inside another list, like this:

```
var queries = (from item in list
               from item2 in list.anotherlist
               select item2).ToList<MyType>();
```

This will not work:

```
// Gives me a list of List<QueryResult>
var queries = list.Select(item => item.anotherlist).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SelectMany operator ought to do the trick - in this case, it takes a list of lists and flattens it:

```
var queries = list.SelectMany(sublist => sublist).ToList();
```

Comment: +1. Just for completeness' sake, I'll add that `from … from … select …` in a LINQ expression is actually equivalent to `SelectMany`; it won't translate to `Select`. See e.g. [this query expression translation cheat sheet by Bart de Smet](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/08/30/c-3-0-query-expression-translation-cheat-sheet.aspx) or the [C# 3.0 specification](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/8/8/388e7205-bc10-4226-b2a8-75351c669b09/CSharp%20Language%20Specification.doc), section 7.15.2.4.

Answer (score 0):

use selectmany

```
var queries = list.SelectMany(l => l.anotherList).ToList();
```